# Powershell || Patttern matching in large file and printing nearby lines

Tags: regex, powershell, scripting

I have a very big file like contains below sample data.

```
blah
---BLOCK SEPERATOR ---
blah
blah
there can be variable
number
of blah
MATCHING PATTERN
again
varying
number of
blah
---BLOCK SEPERATOR ---
blah
variable
blah
again
---BLOCK SEPERATOR ---
```

Now, I want to extract the block which only contains MATCHING PATTERN.
As the file is very big I was using `readcount 500` as suggested in other questions. Also I wanted to print nearby line so I used `select-string -pattern <Pattern> -context 100,100`.
But they both are not working together, even if they work there I am not sure how many block separators will be captured in 100 lines, so I will have take the 
found lines and use regex on them to get the exact block.
Right now I can't use the regex as file is very big and it is taking very long to get read whole file.

What I ideally want is to match the pattern and then extract the line till the block separator on both side. Please mind the file is very big, `readcount` works but it is not working in conjunction with select string.

Please let me know if the problem is not clear also what can be the suitable heading for the question.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
$rawData = @"
blah
---BLOCK SEPERATOR ---
blah
blah
there can be variable
number
of blah
MATCHING PATTERN
again
varying
number of
blah
---BLOCK SEPERATOR ---
blah
variable
blah
again
---BLOCK SEPERATOR ---
"@

$rawData -split "---BLOCK SEPERATOR ---" | Where-Object {$_ -like "*MATCHING PATTERN*"}
```

Comment: the file is very big, I can't take the whole thing into memory

Comment: The you're probably going to want to look at the .NET `.ReadLine()` and similar methods (that you can invoke via PowerShell) if required. @tollboy